# Cron job failing - wrong PHP version?

Tags: php, laravel, cron, laravel-artisan

**Works on local WAMP**

`php artisan schedule:run` works as expected on my local WAMP.

**Error: When running on web hosted server**

When I run `php artisan schedule:run` on my webhosting server it crashes. **Error log**:

> **Parse error**:  syntax error, unexpected 'class' (T_CLASS), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$' in **/var/sites/p/mysite.com/delayed/artisan** on line **30**

**What I think it is: PHP version issue**

Believe it is a php version error issue (cron job on hosted server is 5.3 and L5 requires 5.5.9...)
http://laravel.io/forum/06-10-2015-laravel-5-error-on-installation

**Simple fix does not work**

I implemented the solution to add `#!/usr/bin/php-5.6/php-cli` at the top of my artisan file in accordance with http://laravel.io/forum/03-03-2015-console-command-fails-when-executed-by-cpanel

But it does not 'bite', when runnning `php-5.6 artisan schedule:run` on the shell it generates

> Running scheduled command: 'usr/local/bin/php' 'artisan' download:delays > 'var/sites/p/mysite.com/delayed/storage/logs/cron.log' 2>&1

That means it will fire the 'standard' php, which unfortunately for my web provider is 5.3 on cronjobs..

**QUESTION: HOW DO I GET CRON JOB TO FIRE PHP 5.6?**

Any ideas on how to get the artisan to fire php5.6 rather than server default?

Comment: so show the actual code causing this error...

Comment: if server php version is incompatible then move hosts

Comment: Does the the hosting provider offer any other version of PHP? Some providers allow you to switch the PHP version from the control panel. Either way, I suggest you take this up with them, as offering support for these kind of issues is their responsibility, before thinking of switching hosts as @Dagon suggested.

Comment: When you run jobs from cron, you may not have the same PATH variable that you have at the command line.  This means that if multiple PHP versions are installed `php` may point to something different in cron.  Solution: use the full path to the correct PHP binary in cron (i.e. `/path/to/correct/version/php foo.php`)

Comment: I'm with Marc. What does line 30 of artisian look like

Comment: @Mr.Llama Stupid question from my side: But where do I put the statement? (i.e. /path/to/correct/version/php). Php artisan schedule:run fires Laravel's Kernel.php - is this where I would add it at the top? Or in the artisan file? (tried the latter without success ;( )

@MarcB @Kyle Burkett artisan on line 30 has `$kernel = $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Console\Kernel::class);`

Comment: @KyleBurkett The error is definitely a PHP version issue as **Class name resolution via ::class** was added only in PHP 5.5, and Laravel 5.1 and above uses it everywhere.

Comment: @PederWessel what @Mr.Llama means is that your cron job command should use a full path to the PHP binary like so `* * * * * /path/to/correct/version/php /path/to/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1`

Comment: @Bogdan Thanks for the response. When I run `/usr/bin/php-5.6 /var/sites/p/mysite.com/delayed artisan schedule:run` the shell still fires `Running scheduled command: '/usr/local/bin/php' 'artisan' which indicates that it still does not fire 5.6 but the standard php - am I making a mistake here or is there something else I can try?

Comment: Is there a PHP binary for PHP 5.6 named `php-5.6` located in the `/usr/bin` directory? Does running `/usr/bin/php-5.6  -v` output version information about PHP 5.6?

Comment: @Bogdan Yes. /usr/bin/php-5.6 -v outputs `PHP 5.6.8 (cgi-fcgi)` etc.

Feels like there is a small setting I need to change somwhere and I'll be back on track - but I don't know what.. Thanks for your help btw!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is to apply -cli at the end of the php for the cron job.

Changed:

`/usr/bin/php-5.6 /var/sites/p/mysite.com/delayed/artisan schedule:run`

to:

`/usr/bin/php-5.6-cli /var/sites/p/mysite.com/delayed/artisan schedule:run`

Thanks Mr Llama and Bogdan for sending me in the right direction!

Hope this helps someone else with a similar problem in the future.